# How to send extent report in email to stackholders after running all the test cases in cucumber?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, extentreports

I want to send an email with extent report attachment that I have generated. I am using cucumber. Currently report is generated using latest timestamp with below name

```
D:\DAAutomation1\NewFeature1\output\10062021_071218798\Report_10062021_071218798.html
```

Now I want to send this dynamically generated report in email. I am trying to send using the below code in `SequentialRunnerTest`but it is not working.

1. How can I attach a dynamically generated report which stored in a dynamically generated folder?
2. From which location I need to call this code?

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void Setup() {
        
        if (CustomFormatter.getReportInstance() == null) {

            Date d = new Date();
            String today = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.SCREENSHOT_SDF).format(d);
            String reportName = String.format("Report_%s%s", today, Constants.HTML_EXTENSION);

            File dir = new File(today);
            dir = new File(Constants.REPORT_PATH + dir);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir();
                Variables.reportFolderName = dir;
            }
            reportPath = new File(dir + "/" + reportName);
            File folderPath = new File(dir + "/");

            CustomFormatter.initiateCustomFormatter(reportPath, folderPath);

            File extentConfig = new File(Constants.CONFIG_FILES_URI + Constants.EXTENT_FILE);
            CustomFormatter.loadConfig(extentConfig);
            CustomFormatter.addSystemInfo("user", System.getProperty("user.name"));
            CustomFormatter.addSystemInfo("os", System.getProperty("os.name"));
            CustomFormatter.addSystemInfo("browser", CONFIG.getProperty("browser"));
            CustomFormatter.addSystemInfo("Tenant", CONFIG.getProperty("application.url"));

        } else {
            CustomFormatter.initiateCustomFormatter();
        }
```

```
@AfterClass
   public static void SendEmail() throws EmailException {
   // Create the attachment
   EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();

              attachment.setPath(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"output/folderPath/"+reportPath);
   

              attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
                  attachment.setDescription(" Test Execution Report");
                  attachment.setName("Automation Test Execution Report");
         
                  // Create the email message
                  MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
                  email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
                  email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
                  email.setSmtpPort(465);
                  email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("xyz@gmail.com", "xyz@123"));
                  email.addTo("xyz@gmail.com", "Test");
                  email.setFrom("xyz@gmail.com", "Me");
                  email.setSubject("Automation Test Execution Report");
                  email.setMsg("Automation Test Execution Report");
         
                  // add the attachment
                  email.attach(attachment);
         
                  // send the email
                  email.send();
            }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: No error This email code is not running

Comment: Posted an answer. Please see and let me know the result.

Answer (score 1):

please write seperate simple java program that should be **executed after your cucumber run**.

After the **complete execution** only, you will see the **latest report** in your **target folder**. your **secondary program** should **pick** the report from the target folder and **mail** to them.

**In My case,**
I have written separate java program and **JAR packed** that will do following actions,

1. **Zip** screenshot, css and html report from target folder,
2. **Move** them to separate folder with current date and time **to identify**
3. Then **mail** the zip folder

**My Execution like,**

1. Created a .bat/sh file
2. added my cucumber execution
3. added secondary program execution as JAR execution

> mvn test -DCucumber.Options="--tags @temp"
>
> **java** -jar **ZippingAndEmailing**.jar [**reportLocation**] [**targetlocation**] [**emailReciptents**]

> java -jar **ZippingAndEmailing.jar** target/cucumber Results **jayanthbala1993@gmail.com**

Answer (score 0):

> From which location I need to call this code?

You have to call that under `@AfterClass` as you want to send report after executing all tests.

```
@AfterClass
    public static void sendReport()  {
        SendReport sendReport = new SendReport();
        sendReport.triggerMail("Report", "\\NewFeature1\\output\\10062021_071218798\\Report_10062021_071218798.html);
    }
```

> How can I attach a dynamically generated report which stored in a
> dynamically generated folder

```
public class SendReport{

public String[] ToAdresses = { "nandan@gmail.com"
            ,"nandan2@gmail.com" 

public void triggerMail(String reportName, String reportPath)
            throws IOException, AddressException, MessagingException {

    Properties sysmProp = System.getProperties();
    sysmProp.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    sysmProp.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    sysmProp.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    sysmProp.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    sysmProp.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    sysmProp.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    /*Create session object*/
    Session session = Session.getInstance(sysmProp, null);

    /*Create MimeMessage object and add recipients */
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    /* Setting the string value type as address */
            InternetAddress[] recipients = new InternetAddress[ToAdresses.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < ToAdresses.length; i++) {
            recipients[i] = new InternetAddress(ToAdresses[i]);
        }

    /* Adding the recipients to the message object. */
    for (int j = 0; j < ToAdresses.length; j++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients[j]);
        }

     message.setSubject("Test report");
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
     messageBodyPart.setText("Body of email.")

    /* Adding the attachment to the mail. */
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + reportPath);
    BodyPart messageBodyPart_2 = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
    messageBodyPart_2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart_2.setFileName("Test_" + reportName + ".html");

    /* Clubbing the subject of mail. */
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart_2);
    message.setContent(multipart);

    /* Triggers mail. */
    Transport.send(message);

  }
}
```